# Branding Apache Felix web console

Tags: osgi, apache-felix

I am trying to brand a Apache Felix web console, but I am not able to find resource for the same. As per Apache Felix website,

> Branding for the Web Console can be provided in two ways: By registering a BrandingPlugin service or by providing a branding properties files. The Web Console uses the branding from the BrandingPlugin service registered with the highest ranking.

But I am not understanding how to register a BrandingPlugin service? What and Jar files should I put? Is there any guidance or tutorial available for the same? If yes, can you guide me in this?

Since I am totaly getting confused with Apache Felix's website, since those documents are not clear on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find it helpful to do some background reading on [OSGi services](http://www.vogella.com/articles/OSGiServices/article.html). OSGi provides a service registry, and most interactions in an OSGi environment are handled by registering and consuming services. It doesn't matter what jar file you put the service in; the only thing that matters is the interface name its registered under.

You can register services in lots of ways; programmatically from a BundleActivator, using Declarative Services (also known as SCR), and using Blueprint are some of the most popular patterns. Which one is easiest for you depends on how you're building your jars and what other OSGi facilities you're using. If you've already got an Activator the programmatic route may be the quickest way to get started; if you're using the Maven bundle plugin you may find SCR annotations easiest.

What you'll need to do is include an implementation of the 'BrandingPlugin' interface in a jar which gets started by your OSGi runtime, and register that implementation as an OSGi service. Once you've done this you should see that the Felix console discovers your BrandingPlugin implementation and uses it.